# Prevent submission of words already stored in database and echo an alert notifying user that his submission already exists

Tags: php, sql, database

Everything works with my site and database.

I've submitted a snippet of code where I think the PHP to prevent duplicate submissions needs to be inserted.

```
{
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=', '', '');
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
  include 'error.html.php';
  exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['profanetext']))
{
  try
  {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO profane SET
        profanetext = :profanetext,
        profanedate = CURDATE()';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':profanetext', $_POST['profanetext']);
    $s->execute();

  }


  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
    $error = 'Error adding submitted profanity: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
  }

  header('Location: .');
  exit();

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Mazz

I am trying to figure out what php code I need to add to what I already have so that when a user submits a word or phrase that has already been submitted to my database, the submission is rejected and an alert notifies the user that his or her submission already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You do a select where query to see if the value exist first.

Also you can make the actual profane text database column UNIQUE. This will prevent insertion of duplicate value and will produce an db error if trying to do so.

Comment: many thanks for your advice, but I'm about to pull my hair out. Ha! I tried to assign UNIQUE to column profanetext using this command: alter table profane ADD UNIQUE(profanetext); That returned this error: #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'profanetext' used in key specification without a key length So I tried to do it with a key length, like so: alter table profane ADD UNIQUE(profanetext(255)); And got this error message: #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'profanetext'

Comment: I tried the following select where query, but it didn't work. if (isset($_POST['profanetext'])) { try { $sql = 'INSERT INTO profane SET profanetext = :profanetext, profanedate = CURDATE()'; $s = $pdo->prepare($sql); $s->bindValue(':profanetext', $_POST['profanetext']); $profanetext = $_POST['profanetext']; $query = "SELECT * FROM profane WHERE profanetext = '{$profanetext}'"; $result = mysql_query($query); if ( $sql_num_rows ( $result ) > 1 ) { echo 'That profanity has already been submitted'; }

Comment: OK, I ended up making the unique column for profanetext work, but I would rather do something that results in an alert rather than a db error -- as the db error loads as another page, and isn't very user friendly. To the average user, the db error will appear to them as if the site is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out a way to make it work. After changing the profanetext column from TEXT type to VARCHAR(255) -- which allowed me to make the column UNIQUE -- I added this to my php to make the db error message display as an alert:

```
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error adding submitted profanity: ' . $e->getMessage();
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("That profanity has already been submitted")';
echo '</script>';
exit();
}
```